# Using Activesync with folders in inbox

Tags: email, exchange, active-sync

I recently purchased Note II and am using the stock email. This is a exchange connection and use rules to push email to folders. I can see the folders and get notifications when new mail arrives however if more than one email arrives and is pushed to different folders the notification does not indicate where the email is and so the search begins. The folders do not show unread emails only all emails in the folder read or not. Any ideas.

Comment: Created this enhancement request in the code review. The more stars the better chance it will be looked at. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40977&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&start=400